# How to stop Rainlendar from hiding on the Linux Mint desktop?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, desktop, cinnamon, application

[Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net) is a great tool to keep events and tasks on the desktop (I did not find a better solution yet).

The problem is that the application completely hides if you press:

- The "Show Desktop" button of Mint's panel (taskbar)
- <kbd>Special-Key + d</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL + ALT + d</kbd>

Possible Rainlendar position settings:

- *On Top* - Does not work
- *Normal* - Does not work
- *On Bottom* - Does not work
- *On Desktop* - With this option, the application won't hide, but would be on top of every window. So this isn't really a solution.

**Is it possible to prevent Rainlendar from hiding or is there at least a command to show Rainlendar again (at the moment I have to kill the process and start it again) or any other solution?**

I'm using:

- Linux Mint 15 "Olivia" with Cinnamon 1.8.8
- Rainlendar 2.11.1

Everything is up-to-date at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things, I ended up with this:
Just do right click on the application's tray icon (usually a little calendar) and click "Refresh". This will make the application visible again.

On Linux Mint with the Cinnamon desktop: The tray icon is only visible if the App Indicator Icon option is **disabled** (which is enabled by default)!

To disable the App Indicator Icon go to: Options->Advanced->"Show app indicator icon"

Comment: come here from ubuntu but cannot see tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rainlendar FAQ](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php?option=com_easyfaq&Itemid=26#faq19):

> **Rainlendar gets hidden when I click the "Show Desktop" button.** 
> Written by Kimmo Pekkola
>
> Change the window position to "On Desktop". If that doesn't work, use the "On Top" position or learn to use Win+M to minimize the applications (Shift+Win+M brings them back).

Comment: That doesn't work for me. According to my question: "On Desktop" is not a solution to live with and "On Top" does not work. Win+M may works only on Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked for me.

- Choose "On Desktop" as Position
- Go to options -> Advanced -> Windows

  Change "transparency type" parameters to "copy".

[image: railendar option]

Voila, widget now will always stand on the desktop.

Even if you hide all windows or do <kbd>cmd/win</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> command.